# How to use the shell to delete excess characters conditionally?

Tags: text-processing, sed

I don't know if this can be done with simple Unix commands to implement it. Because it looks a bit complicated.

I have a text that looks like the following.

```
<p id="mt">Iusto, numquam dolore aut voluptates delectus</p>
<p id="mt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p id="mt">Facere vitae sapiente necessitatibus</p>
<p id="mt">Tempora modi rem reprehenderit quam eos. Provident, animi ab ducimus dolorem</p>
```

Each line has different character lengths, and some content is too long and requires omission of excess portions.

For example, limit the `<p id="mt">...</p>` content to 20 characters and delete them if you go beyond that. It looks like this.

```
<p id="mt">Iusto, numquam dolor</p>
<p id="mt">Lorem ipsum dolor si</p>
<p id="mt">Facere vitae sapient</p>
<p id="mt">Tempora modi rem rep</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/^(<p id="mt">.{20}).*(<\/p>$)/\1\2/' infile
```

Comment: This will print the `</p>` twice in case the length is in the range 16...19.

Comment: @RakeshSharma fixed, thanks

Answer (score 1):

command

```
awk -F ">" '{print $2}' filename| awk -F "<" '{print "<p id=\"mt\">"substr($1,1,20)"</p>"}'
```

output

```
<p id="mt">Iusto, numquam dolor</p>
<p id="mt">Lorem ipsum dolor si</p>
<p id="mt">Facere vitae sapient</p>
<p id="mt">Tempora modi rem rep</p>




Python

m=open('filename','r')
for g in m:
    e=g.split('>')[1].split('<')[0][0:20]
    print "<p id=\"mt\"> {0}</p>".format(e)
```

output

```
<p id="mt"> Iusto, numquam dolor</p>
<p id="mt"> Lorem ipsum dolor si</p>
<p id="mt"> Facere vitae sapient</p>
<p id="mt"> Tempora modi rem rep</p>
```